# Why doesn't WhatsApp encryption multiply file size

Tags: encryption

WhatsApp uses and end-to-end encryption, on both personal and group chats.
According to my understanding, that means every message I send to a group  is encrypted on my Device for every group member separately and is sent separately to everyone

If I understood properly, this is why WhatsApp group chats are limited to 256 members.

And here comes my question:

Why doesn't sending large files on WhatsApp groups require much data and takes much time?

If a group contains hundreds of people, sending a small movie has to cost hundreds of megabytes, but actually it doesn't!

Comment: According to [this trick from quoara](https://www.quora.com/What-are-good-ways-to-add-3000-users-in-a-whatsapp-group), you can add 3000 users to a group.

Comment: I think, this question has been answered our venerable sister site Information Security [How does WhatsApp's new group chat protocol work and what security properties does it have?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119633/how-does-whatsapps-new-group-chat-protocol-work-and-what-security-properties-do/119656)

Comment: That is the trick. `The sender individually encrypts the Sender Key to each member of the group, using the pairwise messaging protocol explained previously. For all subsequent messages to the group:`